# Excel formula to the value of a cell based on two cells' values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I might be asking for too much here but this is also a part of the requirement that I am working on from the below excel table I would like find the value of a specified cell if I give two different values and I would like to achieve that with the `OFFSET`, `MATCH`, `INDEX` functions in excel.

There are two scenarios

Scenario 1:

> If I give value1=3500 (which is not in the first column) and value2=75 the Result1=1.59 and Result2=1.89

Scenario 2:

> If I give value1=3500 and value2=85 (both the values are not in the first row and first column of the grid) the resulting value should be Result1=1.59, Result2=1.89, Result3=1.51, Result4= 1.81`

How can I achieve this within excel?

```
Measure |2.5    |5      |10     |25     |50     |75     |100    |150    |200    
250     |0.835  |0.75   |0.69   |0.6    |0.528  |0.455  |0.383  |0.314  |0.245  
500     |1.044  |0.938  |0.863  |0.75   |0.675  |0.6    |0.525  |0.451  |0.378  
1000    |1.391  |1.25   |1.15   |1      |0.923  |0.845  |0.768  |0.689  |0.61   
2000    |1.948  |1.75   |1.52   |1.4    |1.321  |1.243  |1.164  |1.083  |1.002  
3000    |2.435  |2.188  |1.95   |1.75   |1.67   |1.59   |1.51   |1.426  |1.343  
4000    |2.853  |2.563  |2.3    |2.05   |1.97   |1.89   |1.81   |1.726  |1.643  
5000    |3.507  |3.15   |2.675  |2.4    |2.269  |2.188  |2.107  |2.021  |1.936  
10000   |       |4.553  |4      |3.72   |3.56   |3.477  |3.394  |3.304  |3.215  
15000   |       |5.691  |5      |4.6    |4.469  |4.385  |4.301  |4.209  |4.117  
20000   |       |6.545  |5.8    |5.3    |5.151  |5.066  |4.981  |4.888  |4.795  
25000   |       |7.527  |6.4    |5.83   |5.666  |5.573  |5.48   |5.377  |5.274  
50000   |       |9.785  |8.32   |7.579  |7.366  |7.245  |7.123  |6.99   |6.856
```

Comment: Start by comparing the results of an exact MATCH() (last parameter=0) with one using 1 as the last parameter: if the first one returns an error then you know you need to return multiple values (for the second values in each direct add 1 to the values you pass to `OFFSET()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your workbook is placed into the named range Measure(B2:J13), Value 1(B15) and Value 2(B16), then the formulas:

```
=INDEX(Measure,MATCH(Value_1,$A$2:$A$13,1),MATCH(Value_2,$B$1:$J$1,1))
=INDEX(Measure,MATCH(Value_1,$A$2:$A$13,1),MATCH(Value_2,$B$1:$J$1,1)+1)
=INDEX(Measure,MATCH(Value_1,$A$2:$A$13,1)+1,MATCH(Value_2,$B$1:$J$1,1))
=INDEX(Measure,MATCH(Value_1,$A$2:$A$13,1)+1,MATCH(Value_2,$B$1:$J$1,1)+1)
```

will return the values you require. Use the `MATCH` function to select the row, selectively offset it with the `+ 1` (or similar) and then use `INDEX` to select the item in the table.

The table layout is cosmetic. Nothing prevents the column and row labels from being elsewhere entirely. The Named ranges reference the input values.

Additional input values of 1000, 10 return the results 1.15, 1, 1.52, 1.4.

Comment: I recreated the workbook and confirmed it returns the correct results with a corrected range. I get your results if the Measure named range starts at A1 instead of B2 as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve only just noticed this problem when browsing through stackoverflow today, and since it was never actually addressed in its entirety, I’ve decided to answer it for future reference by individuals facing the same problem.

This is ***one*** of the many possible approaches to this question:

Assume the Measure table is placed in the range A1:J13 of an Excel worksheet, Value 1 is in the cell A16, Value 2 is in the cell C16 and Result values 1 to 4 are stored in the cell range E16:F17, then we can use the following formulae in Excel 2010/2013 to extract the information which you require:

In cell E16 (the cell storing the value for Result 1), enter the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(MATCH(A16,A1:A13,0),FALSE), IFERROR(MATCH(C16,A1:J1,0),FALSE)),INDEX((OFFSET($A$1:$J$13,(MATCH(A16,A1:A13,0)-1),(MATCH(C16,A1:J1,0)-1))),1,1), INDEX((OFFSET($A$1:$J$13,(MATCH(A16,A1:A13,1)-1),(MATCH(C16,A1:J1,1)-1))),1,1))
```

In cell E17 (the cell storing the value for Result 2), enter the following formula:

```
=IF((IFERROR(MATCH(A16,A1:A13,0),FALSE))," ", INDEX((OFFSET($A$1:$J$13,(MATCH(A16,A1:A13,1)),(MATCH(C16,A1:J1,1)-1))),1,1))
```

In cell F16 (the cell storing the value for Result 3), enter the following formula:

```
=IF((IFERROR(MATCH(C16,A1:J1,0),FALSE)),"",INDEX((OFFSET($A$1:$J$13,(MATCH(A16,A1:A13,1)-1),(MATCH(C16,A1:J1,1)))),1,1))
```

In cell F17 (the cell storing the value for Result 4), enter the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(MATCH(A16,A1:A13,0),FALSE)=FALSE, IFERROR(MATCH(C16,A1:J1,0),FALSE)=FALSE),INDEX((OFFSET($A$1:$J$13,(MATCH(A16,A1:A13,1)),(MATCH(C16,A1:J1,1)))),1,1)," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps, the following formulae seem to display the values at the corners, assuming Measure is a named range starting in A1 and value1 and value2 are named ranges:

> =INDEX(Measure,IFERROR(MATCH(value1,A:A,0),MATCH(value1,A:A,1)),IFERROR(MATCH(value2,1:1,0),MATCH(value2,1:1,1)))
>
> =INDEX(Measure,IFERROR(MATCH(value1,A:A,0),MATCH(value1,A:A,1)),IFERROR(MATCH(value2,1:1,0),MATCH(value2,1:1,1)+1))
>
> =INDEX(Measure,IFERROR(MATCH(value1,A:A,0),MATCH(value1,A:A,1)+1),IFERROR(MATCH(value2,1:1,0),MATCH(value2,1:1,1)))
>
> =INDEX(Measure,IFERROR(MATCH(value1,A:A,0),MATCH(value1,A:A,1)+1),IFERROR(MATCH(value2,1:1,0),MATCH(value2,1:1,1)+1))

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want but here is my try:

Enter following formula for `B19`, then copy&paste to all cell in green table.

`=IF(OR(AND($B$15=$A19,$B$16=B$18),AND($B$15>$A18,$B$15<$A20,$B$16>A$18,$B$16<C$18)),B2,0)`

[image]